# laravel : what is best way to replace with `foreach ( Mymodel :: all ( ) as $object)`?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, foreach, accessor

I have a `cart` model that have an accessor method call `isFullAccepted()` that return `true/false` after checking a relationship states.

in another one accessor call `remaingingCarts()` I return all `carts` that it's `isFullAccepted()` is false.

in the `remaingingCarts()` accessor is :

```
public function remainingCarts(){
    $carts = Cart::all();
    $cartIds = [];
    foreach($carts as $cart){
        if (!$cart->isFullAccepted()){
            array_push($cartIds , $cart->id);
        }
    }
    return Cart::findMany($cartIds);
}
```

is this way fast ?

`foreach` on `all()` Does not create heavy processing ?

Comment: It does. You can use a JOIN or a subquery instead but its difficult to answer this question without knowing details of the relationship.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must try where condition.

```
public function remainingCarts(){
    $carts = Cart::where('is_full_accepted',false)->get();
    return $carts;
}
```

If you are getting Carts which `isFullAccepted` is false, try this.

Comment: `is_full_accepted` is not a field in database, it is a method.

Comment: Do you share this method ?